# Solve $\,f(x)<x\,$ instead of $\,x<f^{-1}(x)\,.$

Tags: functions, inequality, inverse-function

Suppose for a given function $f(x)$ we want to solve the inequation $x<f^{-1}(x)$. As you know the inverse of a function is its reflection over the line $y=x$. So I believe it kind of makes sence to say in places where $x<f^{-1}(x)$ then $f(x)<x$ because when the $f^{-1}$ is on top of the line $y=x$, its reflection -which is $f(x)$- is under the line. That's the case for some functions like $f(x)=0.5x+1$.

[image: f(x)=0.5x+1]

but if we take $f(x)=1/x$ this trick does not work because the inverse of the function is itself and where $x<f^{-1}(x)$ also $x<f(x)$.

[image: f(x)=1/x]

I wanted to know if the above trick was just lucky or not and if not, are there any general rules to know if we can apply this trick to a certain function or not?

Comment: Applying $f$ to an inequality preserves it if $f$ is strictly increasing, and reverses it if strictly decreasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, let's agree that it is certainly true that if $a = b$ then $f(a) = f(b)$,
where $f$ is any function you like.

But when you try to solve $x < f^{-1}(x)$ by applying $f$ to both sides and claiming that $$f(x) < f(f^{-1}(x)) = x,$$
you are assuming that if
$ a < b $
then $f(a) < f(b)$, where $a = x$ and $b = f^{-1}(x).$

For some functions it is indeed true that for any numbers $a$ and $b,$
if $ a < b $ then $f(a) < f(b).$
Such a function is called an *increasing function*.

The fact that we call some functions "increasing functions" should make you wonder if there are functions that are not increasing. And indeed there are such functions.
There is such a thing as a function $g$ such that whenever $a < b,$
then $g(a) > g(b).$
The function $g(x) = 1/x$ on the positive real numbers is such a function.
And it does exactly the opposite of what you want.

There can even be an invertible function that is neither increasing nor decreasing.
consider the function
$$
h(x) = \begin{cases} \dfrac2x & x > 0, \\[1ex] \dfrac x2 & x \leq 0. \end{cases}
$$

You can confirm that this function is invertible. But $h(-2) < h(-1)$
while $h(1) > h(2).$ The first inequality says the function is not a decreasing function, while the second says it is not an increasing function.

So in general, if a function is increasing, then you can solve $x < f^{-1}(x)$
by solving $f(x) < x$;
if a function is decreasing, you can solve $x < f^{-1}(x)$ by solving $f(x) > x$;
but if the function is neither increasing nor decreasing then you must be more careful.

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful.